# A question was deleted; how do I recover my answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, undelete, answered-questions

The question was "Learning Lua (fast)"; it was asked years ago and was closed soon after I answered it.

It has been recently deleted, but I would like to recover the content of my answer.

I wrote a long introduction to Lua as my answer, and would like to post it on my blog.

How do I recover my answer?

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092382/learning-lua-fast/8097810#8097810

Comment: [Here you go](http://pastebin.com/vhVmiRxp).

Comment: IMO best way is asking politely in some relevant chat room, where you know high rep users are roaming. But asking here usually works too. :)

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users with access to [moderation tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can view deleted questions. On Stack Overflow, that privilege is earned at 10,000 rep points (and, of course, diamond moderators have it). Your best bet is probably to ask one of those people via a meta post or in chat.

I see Shadow Wizard was [kind enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246275/a-question-was-deleted-how-do-i-recover-my-answer#comment806080_246275) to get you a copy of your answer in a comment above, so mission accomplished!

In the future, you might be better-off asking on Meta Stack Overflow, but I don't think it's much of a big deal for questions like this.

I didn't bother saying this in the first place, but given that this question and answer have been fairly well-received it's probably worth noting explicitly, I wouldn't make a habit out of doing this. It's fine here or there, but ultimately there's no obligation for 10K'ers to do this for anyone, and people might start getting annoyed if it happens a lot. Again, I don't get the impression it would (it's not often answers worth keeping get deleted), but yeah.

---

**Editor's note:** Note that since this answer was posted, it's now possible for users to view their own deleted answers if the question they answered got deleted, provided it's less than 60 days old, or if not, you have the link to it. If you don't, you'll still need to ask another user for it.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)